# Java application crashes my computer. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-xp, java, crash, sp3, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 4.1 for my university course (this is an older version, but is the required version for the course - I can't use a newer version).

Whenever I use it for longer than several minutes, my computer crashes - it either reboots or I need to reset it.

I have tried running with all startup items disabled (to rule out other applications interfering with the app), but it did no good.

I have used Sysinternals procmon logging and the logs are corrupt - the only way I was able to get a good log was by enabling boot logging. However these are huge and I don't know what to look for.

I am using Windows XP SP3, fully patched up and this is the only application that I have any kind of problem with.

Can anyone suggest troubleshooting steps that will help me pinpoint the cause of these crashes and fix them?

Comment: what java version are you running?

Comment: 1.6 standard edition

Comment: too new, try 1.4.2.  if that doesn't work you might be running into an incompatibility with XP-SP3, try it on an XP-SP2 system.

Comment: Could it be a memory fault? NetBeans is not light, and it's possible that it is causing memory to be used that normally doesn't get touched. I suggest running some memory diagnostics.

Comment: I have run mem86 on this machine before, and I am using other memory heavy apps, so that's not it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the system event logs. **Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer management**, expand **Event Viewer** and look at application and system logs for anything unusual, the entries at the top should be most recent, sort by time if not.

Also check the Java console for errors. When a Java application is running, right click the Java icon in the tray and select "Open 1.X.XX Console" where the `X`s are replaced with your current version.

If you are running a very recent version of Java, it could have broken compatibility with the old Netbeans release. Check the release date for your specific Netbeans version, and download the corresponding JRE that was released at that time to ensure maximum compatibility. You can find older JRE versions [here](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/).

Comment: Nothing in the logs. In regards to the JRE version - apparently it is distributed with the correct JRE version.

Comment: It's distributed with it, but is it using the old one? Check your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Netbeans 4.1 was released in May of 2005 and was tested with `J2SE JDK 5.0`.  the release notes indicate it should also run on `J2SE SDK v1.4.2`.  see http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/41/ and http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/41/relnotes.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the problem is caused by NetBeans 4.1, have you tried to reinstall NetBeans?

Try to uninstall and reinstall it with the minimum installation that fits your needs.
If you have any plugins, do not install them to start with.

Take a backup of the NetBeans directory(ies) before you start, to be able to undo it if things turn bad, and delete any remainders left behind in the directory after the uninstallation.

Comment: I did uninstall and reinstall. No joy :(